# How to edit JWT middleware [Laravel 5.2]

Tags: laravel-5, jwt

I am using `Tymon` pkg for JWT, in my `Kernel.php` I have like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
 'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
 'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
...
```

How can I change that middlewares?